# How do I get the white box above the truck?

Tags: netlogo

```
breed [squares square]
breed [trucks truck]

to setup
  ca
  create-trucks  1 [truck-init]
  create-squares 1 [square-init]
end

to square-init
  set shape "square"
  set size 4
  set color white
end

to truck-init
  set shape "truck"
  set size 9
  set color red
end
```

I get this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSgEv.png

I want to get the white square above the truck. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetLogo draws the breeds in the order they're declared. So right now, squares are drawn, then trucks are drawn on top of them. Thus, you just need to switch the order that breeds are declared, like so:

```
breed [trucks truck]
breed [squares square]
```